# Multiple SSDs on an RPi 4

Tags: pi-4, raid

I'm looking to build a RAID 1 setup on a PI to at least have a local NAS, if not a nextcloud-like setup (after two years living on a mobile hotspot, glass fiber is coming this week, yay!)

I am a bit weary when I read about SSD-USB cables not working on RPi's, overdrawing power from the Pi etc. Eventually though, I *think* the below linked items should work. pihut.com claims the cables work with the Pi and the datasheet of the WD Greens state a max power draw of 2.800 mW.

Can anyone advice if an RPi 4 and the items below would be a reliable combination for a RAID 1 setup?

SSDs
https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-green-sata-2-5-ssd#WDS100T3G0A

SSD to USB cable
https://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-sd-cards-and-adapters/products/ssd-to-usb-3-0-cable-for-raspberry-pi

Thanks in advance,
Manno

Comment: I don't use that exact SSD or that exact USB3 to SATA cable, however, the one I use (ugreen brand) uses the exact same chip `ASMedia ASM1153E/ASM225` ... rock solid stellar performance (on cheap SSDs - SiliconPower) - so, I can assure you that at least the cable *should* be fine

Comment: OK, thanks for thee reassurance. I ordered the above items and will dive into the process of setting up RAID and nextcloud soon I suppose :)

Comment: From the datasheet, max write for the WD Green 2 TB is specced at 3100 mW, that makes 6200 mW for 2 drives, max current draw to all USB outlets on the Pi is 1.2 A, (1200 mA) that's 6000 mW (at 5 volts) ignoring any power draw from the lead's chipset, you'll be borderline for 2 x 2 TB. The 1 TB, 480 GB, and 240 GB drives take 2800 mW and the 120 GB drive takes 2200 mW.

Comment: thanks. The 1TB should be OK, right? (I ordered those :) ) 2x2800mW = 5600mW or may there be occasional glitches that close to the limit? Otherwise I guess I'll have to go for something like @Bravo mentions: https://www.ugreen.com/products/sata-to-usb-3-0-adapter-cable?_pos=4&_sid=5d4033a18&_ss=r

Comment: 'Otherwise'? If you use the pi's USB power, if the drives go over 1.2A total at any time, expect filesystem corruption, sudden unmounting, etc, whatever lead or adapter you choose. You could be OK when the drives are idle or just reading, but if both drives start writing together, you could hit the limit.

Comment: "otherwise" = "if so," :)
I have to read up on Ohm's law etc. probably The stats say that the WD Green 1TBs draw 2800mW. The USB ports can deliver 6000mW, right? Then I should be good at all times or is there anything else I need to take into account?